# Travel, visa, and relocating from Syria to the US

Tags: visas, usa, syrian-citizens

As a doctor /MD/ living in Syria with Syrian nationality. How can I enter the USA and finish my exams and work there? Is it impossible?

Comment: Since you want to relocate permanently, the question belongs on Expatriates.SE. But, very broadly speaking, the US does not welcome refugees. The EU doesn't, either, but it has accepted more from the Middle East. The laws expect refugees to stop in the *first safe place* they reach, not in the country of their choice. Consider going somewhere with a points-based immigration law, where degrees count for something.

Comment: Are you fully qualified or still a student? This makes a difference as to whether you can move as a skilled migrant instead of being a refugee.

Comment: Not yet , still doing residency,anesthesiology.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the USA currently (2018.2) has a travel ban for people from Syria that has for the time being [not been ruled unconstitutional by the Supreme Court.](https://www.economist.com/blogs/democracyinamerica/2018/01/travelling-ban)

While the cases are making their way through the system, there’s been an effective halt to new visa processing that will make getting a visa for you exceedingly difficult or impossible in the near future.

You might try another country that would accept your refugee status and welcome your talents. Right now that isn’t the USA.

But you should post this question in expatriates.se as refugee status and emigration aren’t suitable topics for travel.se.

Comment: There are some exceptions to the travel ban, though they will not be easy to achieve for most people.  One way to get into the US would be to get a job in the US with an international organization such as the UN or a diplomatic mission in the US.  I also believe it is illegal to apply the suspension of immigrant visa processing to refugees from Syria, but if I understand correctly the administration is nonetheless doing so, since refugees are only excepted from the ban if they've already been admitted to the US.

Comment: Canada may be a country to consider.  Canada has been accepting Syrian refugees in significant quantity.  However, don't view settling in Canada as a step to settling in the US.

Comment: @phoog - agreed. That is why I say it’s exceedingly difficult or impossible to apply for a new one. There will be a handful of exceptions for young children with family in the USA or someone who has strong connections but not for someone who is resorting to asking random strangers on the internet for advice. As far as international credentials, that’s an interesting line of reasoning. Maybe UN credentials would work. Unfortunately, locals who worked for the US Army with the promise of a visa to the USA have found themselves screwed by the travel ban, which is making the US army’s job difficult

Comment: @RoboKaren "Maybe UN credentials would work": I mention the UN because UN employees and officers enter the country on G visas, which are explicitly excluded from the ban. There are several other international organizations in the US whose employees and officers also use G visas. Diplomatic mission staff use A visas, which enjoy the same exemptions.  The waivers you speak of are examples of "case-by-case waivers" under 3(c) but the diplomatic exception is categorical, under 3(b), like the exception for green card holders. Civilian employees of the DoD do not qualify for these visa categories.